# Group By - but sum one column, and show original columns

Tags: pandas-groupby

I have a 5 column df. I need to groupby by the common names in column A, and sum column B and D. But I need to keep my output that currently sits in columns C through E.
Everytime I groupby its drops columns not involved in the the grouping.
I understand some columns will have 2 non common rows, for a common item in column A, and I need to display both of those values. Hope an example illustrates the problem better.

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 10 | Green | 1 | X |
| Pear | 15 | Brown | 2 | Y |
| Pear | 5 | Yellow | 3 | Z |
| Banana | 4 | Yellow | 4 | P |
| Plum | 2 | Red | 5 | R |

I'd like to output :

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 10 | Green | 1 | X |
| Pear | 20 | Brown | 5 | Y |
|  |  | Yellow |  | Z |
| Banana | 4 | Yellow | 4 | P |
| Plum | 2 | Red | 5 | R |

I cant seem to find the right combination within the groupby function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df_save =df_orig.loc[:, ["A", "C", "E"]]
df_agg = df_orig.groupby("A").agg({"B": "sum", "D" : "sum"}).reset_index()
df_merged = df_save.merge(df_agg)
for c in ["B", "D"] :
    df_merged.loc[df_merged[c].duplicated(), c] = ''
```

| A | C | E | B | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | Green | X | 10 | 1 |
| Pear | Brown | Y | 155 | 23 |
| Pear | Yellow | Z |  |  |
| Banana | Yellow | P | 4 | 4 |
| Plum | Red | R | 2 | 5 |

The above is the output after the operations. I hope this works. Thanks

Comment: works great - any idea the right way to now sort by column D, but keeping rows 2&3 tied to eachother ? Thanks

Comment: Once you are done with above operation, you can do something like, 
`df_merged = df_merged.loc[:, df_orig.columns].`